# Post message to Slack channel as BOT not as APP

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am building a slack app and I am using the chat.postMessage API to post the message to user. I also have a bot user for my app and I am using the bot token for posting the message. When I post the message the message is shown as posted from my app not from my bot means posted message has my App name as the user who posted this message and just next to it 'APP' is written so looks like the app has posted this message but what I want is as I am posting as BOT using the bot token 'BOT' should be written down as with the bots of other slack apps. How do I achieve this. Is there any other parameter I need to pass for doing this. For your information I am passing the value of as_user as default which is true. Please help in achieving the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: You just need to specify a parameter in json as `username:you-bot-username` and that all. While posting message to slack if you use `user:username` then message will be posted with username and if you are using APP or Bot user then you need to specify the parameter `username` on you json payload

Comment: @webDev As you can see in the screenshot in the edited message I have posted the message by setting as_user to false and username as my bot name but still as you can see it is showing APP besides my bot name not as BOT.

Comment: Not possible, this little grey side text is native to Slack. It used to show "BOT" but this text has changed and is now displaying "APP".